# fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory when cross compiling an ARM project on 64bit under WSL

Tags: compiling, gcc, arm

I am trying to compile the Actiontec T3200 Firmware meant for ARM on a 64bit machine using WSL using the ARM toolchain.

I am building using `make PROFILE=963138BGW SHELL=/bin/bash`

The error is `/usr/include/stdint.h:26:36: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory` and I've checked that GCC-Multilib and G++ Multilib are installed

[The error i'm getting in the terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmgBx.png)